# Why the blackbody's spectral emittance isn't a growing exponential in the wavelength?

Tags: thermal-radiation, wavelength

I have read multiple paragraphs about why we do get the bell shaped curve and the tale goes like this, oscillators with high frequency aren't paying the bell getting excited as they would require energetic photons to curry out the mission, hence they are less probable. However, if that was the case, Why oscillators with less frequency aren't dominating the spectrum and we see a bell shaped curve instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the density of states. The number of single photon states between $E$ and $E+dE$ is:

$$ g(E)dE = 8\pi \Big(\frac L{hc}\Big)^3E^2dE $$

Since:

$$ E = h\nu = hc/\lambda $$
$$ dE = \frac{hc}{\lambda^2}d\lambda $$

the wavelength power spectrum ($Eg(E)\propto E^4$) goes as $1/\lambda^5$, so long wavelengths are suppressed. (Here I've left out the Boltzmann factor/partition function normalization parts)